# Simplifying algebraic expressions with fractions in exponential

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

When letting Mathematica simplify

```
(a^(-5) b (a^2 c^3)^3)/((a b^2 )^(-2) c^7)
```

it returns the 'correct' answer

```
a^3 b^5 c^2
```

But, when entering

```
((a^5 b)^(1/2) c^3)/(a^5 (b^4 c^5)^(1/4))
```

the return is far from as 'correct' as the above. (Can it be the 1/2 and 1/4?)

How can I get Mathematica to always return an answer with

```
a^(...) b^(...) c^(...)
```

even if that means (negative) fractions in (...)? And, can negative exponentials be ruled out so that Mathematica responds with a fraction with expressions in numerator and denominator with only positive exponentials? TIA

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand.html) (which implicitly assumes positive real values for variables raised to fractional powers):

```
 PowerExpand[((a^5 b)^(1/2) c^3)/(a^5 (b^4 c^5)^(1/4)) ]
```

> c^(7/4)/(a^(5/2) Sqrt[b])

```
 TeXForm[%]
```

> $\frac {c^{7/4}} {a^{5/2}\sqrt {b}}$

Alternatively, [`Refine`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Refine.html) or [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) with `Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}`:

```
Refine[((a^5 b)^(1/2) c^3)/(a^5 (b^4 c^5)^(1/4)),  Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}]
```

> c^(7/4)/(a^(5/2) Sqrt[b])

```
FullSimplify[((a^5 b)^(1/2) c^3)/(a^5 (b^4 c^5)^(1/4)), 
 Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}]
```

> c^(7/4)/Sqrt[a^5 b]

Comment: (Beat me to it...)

Comment: Just remember that `PowerExpand` results are generally wrong for negative or complex variables.

Comment: Is there some way to avoid square root signs and just return "powers", even if the exponential is a fraction?

Comment: @mf67, you can use `PowerExpand[((a^5 b)^(1/2) c^3)/(a^5 (b^4 c^5)^(1/4))], 
 p : Power[_, Rational[-1 | 1, 2]] :>Inactivate[p, Power]`

Comment: @JohnDoty, good point, yes, _**... the result may not be correct everywhere**_.

Comment: How to convert it to $c^{7/4} a^{-5/2} b^{-1/2}$?